# Getting specific data from proximity sensor (distance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am using Python to read serial data from a proximity sensor, I would like to only get the distance and get rid of all of the other data it is producing. The data it initially outputs is in some sort of Unicode, hexadecimal form. for example:

`b'\xfc\x95\x92\x82\x00\x00F\x00\x1f\x04\xef\xff\xd5\x95\x00\n'`

is the initial output.
When put into a for loop to access data in the line, it then gives me the following numbers.

252
149
146
130
0
0
70
0
31
4
239
255
213

The code I have written so far is:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port = "COM5", baudrate = 230400,  bytesize = 
serial.EIGHTBITS, parity= serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout = 1)
try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print("serial Port is open")
 except:
    print("error")
    exit()
if (ser.isOpen()):
    try:

         while True:

            line = ser.readline()

            print (line)

            for data in line:
                print (data)                 
    except Exception:
                print( "Keyboard Interrupt")
else:
            print("cannnot open port")
```

In the output supplied above ^ wherever it says "255" is the start of a new line and the distance measurement is always located 9 columns down and then will continue to start over again whenever you see "255". To sum it up '255' occurs once every 16 times and then will start a new line of data. I need to be able to access the ninth data item after 255 occurs in order to get the distance.

Here is a longer block of output to give a better example:

`"b'\xfc\xc6\x92O\x00\x00F\x00\x1f\x04\xf1\xff\xd5d\x00\n'`

252
198
146
79
0
0
70
0
31
4
241
255
213
100
0
10
"

`b'\xfc\xc1\x92P\x00\x00I\x00 \x04\xf1\xff\xd5d\x00\n'`

252
193
146
80
0
0
73
0
32
4
241
255
213
100
0
10

`b'\xfc\xc1\x92Q\x00\x00I\x00\x1f\x04\xf1\xff\xd5a\x00\n'`

252
193
146
81
0
0
73
0
31
4
241
255
213
97
0
10

[image: Code and output]